# Find a file for particular date and open it

Tags: linux, shell, unix

So I have multiple files with same name but the file name has a prefix .
Say the file was created today then the name will be `filename-20190318` and for tomorrows file it will be `filename-20190318-1` and so on .

How can I access the file as per the date so if I'm accessing it tomorrow it should show me tomorrows file. And if I want to access the file say from day before it should show me that based on dates.

I tried find command for this `find dir -type f -daystart -mtime -1 -name "*filename*" -exec cat {} \;`

But this results fine for today's file but when I try to fetch for previous day it shows all files from that day to today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to find to access the file with the date:

```
find /dir/ -type f -newerXY 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Example:

```
$ find . -type f -newerat 2017-09-25 ! -newerat 2017-09-26
```

Use the below command to see all the file that was created in that particular day:

```
find /dir/ -type f -newerXY 'yyyy-mm-dd' -ls
```

Put date in place of `'yyyy-mm-dd'`.

Comment: Tried this but this is not giving me any output. I tried find . type f -newerat 2019-03-18 ! -newerat 2019-03-17 this gives no data , if i remove the exclamation it shows all the files , also I tried -not in place of ! but no luck .